# Why is it always ByRef when I specify by ByVal?

Tags: vbscript, byref

I am going through ByVal and ByRef [through MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), which mentions when we pass arguments by ByVal, the values are passed by ByVal always.

In my below example it is always passing by ByRef. What am I doing wrong?

```
  Function sampleFunction(ByVal val) 'Even though here i am passing as ByVal it is taking as ByRef
       val=val+1
        sampleFunction=val
    End Function

    x=50
    temp=sampleFunction(x)
    msgbox temp  'prints 51
```

How can I pass arguments by ByVal when returning from a function?

Comment: You seem to be confusing passing variables by reference with the concept of a return value. If you called `msgbox x` after `sampleFunction`, it would print 50.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is accepting the value of `50`. It is then incrementing the variable `val` by one, so that that variable is now `51`. It then sets the return value to the value of `val`, which is 51.

Therefore, your `temp` variable gets assigned to the return value, which is 51. Your `x` variable, however, will still be `50`, because only the value was passed into the function - the `x` parameter was not modified.

If you would have done a `ByRef` here, then `x` would have been 51.